# UIImageView's image property does not assign correctly

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

The two lines of code below are what I find commonly suggested to take the image data from a network stream packaged in an NSData object, convert it to a UIImage, then assign to a UIImageView. But I wasn't seeing any image. As I looked further, I eventually discovered that the image assignment was not "taking" as one might expect. J would receive nil (0) for a value.

```
UIImage * I = [UIImage imageWithData:NextFrame];
[RootView.MyImageView setImage:I];
UIImage * J = [RootView.MyImageView image];
```

I know this is not a lot of information to go on, but I don't have a clue why something this simple is failing or what other information may be interacting with a UIImageView. If anyone has any information on why this might be occurring, I would deeply and graciously appreciate a reply. I have been working on this all day looking at different examples through out the web and they all point me to the first two lines of code above as correct.

PS, this action is taking place in the main thread. I was bit by that bug before.

Comment: 1. Make sure that neither `I` nor `MyImageView` is nil. 2. Don't begin the names of the variables with a capital letter, it's ugly. `camelCapsInstead`

Comment: I is definitely not nil. With no way to see the pixels while as UIImage, I can see the width and height are exactly correct. Just verified MyImageView is not nil also. As for the CamelCase, I am a MS guy and I just cannot help myself. I know it isn't Javaish, but I can't help myself.

Comment: Is the frame of `RootView.MyImageView` set correctly?

Comment: I can see MyImageView. It has the rect I gave it in the IB tool. I set the background color to verify its location and size. In fact it disappears in front of me if I set the size to sizeToFit, since there is no image to size to.

Comment: So, if you log I and RootView.MyImageView they're not nil, but J is? What do you get for those logs?

Comment: I stopped line by line to look with a debugger (I am using a simulator tonight). I could add NSLogs, but I dont think they would reveal any different information.

Comment: NSLog shows the same information.

Comment: What information? I just can't see how this can't work -- if I logs as a UIImage and RootView.MyImageView logs as a UIImageView this should work (Is MyImageView a UIImageView or is it subclassed?).

Comment: see my answer post. I found what was wrong. It surprised me that Objective-C doesn't distinguish case sensitivity well at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. MyImageView was a subclass of UIImageView. That wasn't a problem in and of itself, but when I had an outlet called Image, then it seems to have gotten confused with the image property. Changed the name to MyImage and it worked just fine. It works really well. The concept of the outlet was premature. I don't even know if I need to use it with the property. (I am new to all this iOS framework.)

Thanks for the responses, it made me focus on the image view class more than other aspects of the entire application.